# How to fetch firebase firestore data at locked mode

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have developed an android app using Firebase, cloud firestore at test mode. Test mode means 'Anyone with my database reference will be able to read or write to my database'. Then i have changed the security rules to '**allow read, write: if false**' for prevent this. It is called locked mode.
But at lock mode data is not fetched. There is no proper documentation at google for this. What can i do?

Answer (score 2):

I'd take a look at our [Security Rules documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started), which will explain how to can properly secure your Firestore database. For example:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // only a user can read and write their profile
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    // any authenticated user can read and write messages
    match /rooms/{roomId} {
      match /messages/{messageId} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain the syntax here [@Mike McDonald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3875023/mike-mcdonald)? I've read the documentation, and I'm trying to grant access to a node matching the authenticated user. However, I don't understand the syntax of these rules.